# How to create a semi-circle Physics Body by using sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm creating a semi-circle node when i try to develop a simple sprite kit game, but i wish the physics body of the node just cover the circle object's edge, and the physics body rotates with the circle(to change the physics body programatically), what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do complex shapes using SKPhysicsBody -bodyWithPolygonFromPath:

There are even tools that let you draw your shape and generate the code for you. See this question for examples: [SpriteKit's SKPhysicsBody with polygon helper tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19040144/877465)

Comment: So complicated！what if i just need the edge of the semi-circle?

Comment: Got it. Use CGPathAddArc and [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath] instead of bodyWithPolygonFromPath

Comment: That will give you an edge, not a body. Edges behave a lot differently that bodies and you probably don't want that. You should really use -bodyWithPolygonFromPath:

Comment: Also, read the [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html).