# How to use paths to create a sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I am very new to SpriteKit, and unfortunately cannot find any resources online to find out how this works.  Basically, I have tried to create a diamond (from other's questions and answers on here).  This is what I have:

```
let node = SKShapeNode()

var path:CGMutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 200, 200)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 250, 250)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200, 300)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 150, 250)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200, 200)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
node.path = path;
node.fillColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
self.addChild(node)
```

I have placed this code in the `viewDidLoad`.  However, when I run this, all I get is the grey screen... Can anyone assist me?  And if so, is it possible to do the same for 2/3 of a circle instead of the diamond?  I would like objects to be able to enter the cirlce...
Can anyone also recommend anywhere where I can learn how to create 'paths' around objects?
I've tried using the `bodyWithTexture:alphaThreshold:size:` on the Apple guide, but cannot figure out how this works?
Sorry for such a long question, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: keep in mind that skshapenode is slow, mainly intended for debugging ie don't build all you game graphics with it, use sprites instead

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks.. shall i just use skspritenode then?  And can you recommend anywhere that teaches it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with CGPath can be complicated sometimes, that's why people have built tools like the [SKImport](https://github.com/adriancooney/SKImport) with an awesome [editor](http://adriancooney.github.io/SKImport/Editor), which creates you the objects and the CGPath which you can use in your project.

[image]

[Link to original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040144/spritekits-skphysicsbody-with-polygon-helper-tool)

Comment: thanks but i cannot find a way to use this in swift... it looks like Objective-C.  Any other recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: You can use Objective-C Frameworks in Swift. Check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html