# How to set physicsBody for doting image?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

When I set physicsBody to image with full circle it works fine!
LIKE :

```
sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:sprite.texture size:sprite.size];
```

> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/220px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png

but how to set physicsBody if i have dotted image like :

> http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/geometry/dotted_circle_u25CC_icon_256x256.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpriteKit's SKPhysicsBody with polygon helper tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040144/spritekits-skphysicsbody-with-polygon-helper-tool)

Comment: link in that accepted answer is not available.

Comment: looks like site is down, you can try this editor - http://adriancooney.ie/SKImport/Editor/

Answer (score 0):

this will give you what you want.  just need to add graphics.  you might also want to add them to a parent sprite.  copy and paste it to check it out, then tweak it for your needs.  hope it helps :)

```
let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

for i in 1...8 {

    let circleSection = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 10))
    circleSection.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: circleSection.size)

    let angle = CGFloat(M_PI_4) * CGFloat(i)
    let distFromCtr = CGFloat(100)
    var angleToPt = CGPoint(
        x: cos(angle) * distFromCtr,
        y: sin(angle) * distFromCtr
    )

    angleToPt.x += centerPoint.x
    angleToPt.y += centerPoint.y

    circleSection.position = angleToPt
    circleSection.zRotation = angle + CGFloat(M_PI_2)
    self.addChild(circleSection)
}
```