# Creating custom physic bodies

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to create the physicsbody for a custom image, but it's quite hard to do it the manual way using `CGPath`. On *iOS8*, we can call `bodyWithTexture` method for `SKPhysicsBody`, however in *iOS7*, I have to do it manually.

Is there an easy way for making physics body of complex textures?

[Dazchong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243587/dazchong) site is down and I tried a few other tools which didn't help.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you can try : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23878466/3402095

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. Problem is that I'm using Swift to develop the game and can't use the Objective-C class he has provided. Will it work with a bridger?

Comment: I can't answer that, because I haven't tested it.

Comment: Theres no reason i can think of why it wouldnt work with a bridging header. I've used all kinds of obj-c stuff in my swift project this way. why not try it?