# 1. CGPathMoveToPoint' is unavailable: Use move(to:transform:) 2. 'CGPathAddLineToPoint' is unavailable: Use addLine(to:transform:)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, cgpath

I have created one of my application in `swift 2` in `Xcode 7.3.1`. But now I have open same application in `Xcode 8.0` and perform changes. Some automatic changes are done and some errors and suggestions shown I have corrected them. But I am facing issue that

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, lineFrame.midX, lineFrame.midY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, lineFrame.origin.x + lineFrame.width / 2, lineFrame.origin.y)
```

I tried to create `path`, but shows error that

> 1. `CGPathMoveToPoint` is unavailable: Use move(to:transform:)
> 2. `CGPathAddLineToPoint` is unavailable: Use addLine(to:transform:)

If anyone have solution, please let me know.

Comment: DOFavoriteButton source code?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: lineFrame.midX, y: lineFrame.midY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineFrame.origin.x + lineFrame.width / 2, y: lineFrame.origin.y))
```

And check the latest reference of `CGMutablePath`:

[CGMutablePath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgmutablepath)

Comment: @VRAwesome, that may happen. Please remember you can write an answer by yourself (and accept it later). Good luck for you and for your app.